# ubuntu phone textfield displayed different

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, qml

I am trying to build a QML application for Ubuntu phone.
My form looks ok on screen (desktop), but when I put the app on the phone, the display is off. The borders around my test fields are not visible. See images below.
[image: display on the phone]
[image: display on desktop]

How can I fix this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Small QML file that shows the problem would be useful. Also, maybe run it from the terminal with `QSG_VISUALIZE=overdraw` variable.

Comment: You can find the source of the application at https://github.com/eliwan/xxedule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background of a text field is invisible if this text field is readOnly. For me they are invisible both on the phone and desktop (15.04).

Theme styling file
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/Themes/Ambiance/TextAreaStyle.qml` (qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin:amd64 1.2.1458+15.04.20150422-0ub) shows that it's intentional:

```
property Component background: UbuntuShape {
    property bool error: (styledItem.hasOwnProperty("errorHighlight") && styledItem.errorHighlight && !styledItem.acceptableInput)
    onErrorChanged: (error) ? visuals.errorColor : visuals.backgroundColor;
    color: visuals.backgroundColor;
    anchors.fill: parent
    visible: !styledItem.readOnly
}
```

Ideal workaround (that doesn't work yet because there are no Ubuntu.Components.Styles in this version) is to override the style:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import Ubuntu.Components 1.2
import Ubuntu.Components.Styles 1.2

TextField {
    readOnly: true

    style: TextFieldStyle {
        background: UbuntuShape {
            color: Theme.palette.normal.field
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}
```

For now, I can only think of a hardcoded background like that:

```
TextField {
    readOnly: true

    UbuntuShape {
        z: -1
        color: Theme.palette.normal.field
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```